# macOS Keynote, Pages, Numbers, and Microsoft Office apps will not open

Tags: catalina, ms-office, numbers, performance, pages

From time to time out of the blue all these apps stop open. Other apps like Transmission, Safari, VLC and Mail seem fine as do other preinstalled apps.

Until recently after the system restart everything was working fine, but not anymore. Have 389 GB of free HDD space. I see Sophos mentioned in the reports below (don't understand the meaning of it...): can it be the culprit, by any chance?

**Before the system restart:**

```
EtreCheck version: 3.4.6 (460)
Report generated 2021-05-01 17:45:49
Download EtreCheck from https://etrecheck.com
Runtime: 30:56
Performance: Poor

Click the [Lookup] links for more information from Apple Support Communities.
Click the [Details] links for more information about that line.
Click the [Remove/Report] links to remove adware or update the whitelist of legitimate software.

Hardware Information: ⓘ
    Mac mini (Late 2012) 
    [Technical Specifications] - [User Guide] - [Warranty & Service]
    Mac mini - model: Macmini6,2
    1 2.6 GHz Quad-Core Intel Core i7 (i7-3720QM) CPU: 4-core
    16 GB RAM Upgradeable - [Instructions]
        BANK 0/DIMM0
            8 GB DDR3 1600 MHz ok
        BANK 1/DIMM0
            8 GB DDR3 1600 MHz ok
    Handoff/Airdrop2: supported
    Wireless:  en1: Unknown
    iCloud Quota: 4.97 GB available

Video Information: ⓘ
    Intel HD Graphics 4000 - VRAM: 1536 MB
        HP ZR30w 2560 x 1600

Disk Information: ⓘ
    APPLE HDD HTS541010A9E662 disk0: (1 TB) (Rotational)
    [Show SMART report]
        EFI (disk0s1 - MS-DOS FAT32) <not mounted>  [EFI]: 210 MB 
        (disk0s2) <not mounted>  [APFS Container]: 1000.00 GB

USB Information: ⓘ
     USB20Bus 
         hub_device 
             hub_device 
                Apple, Inc. IR Receiver 
                Apple Inc. BRCM20702 Hub 
                    Apple Inc. Bluetooth USB Host Controller 
     USB20Bus 
         hub_device 
             hub_device 
     USB30Bus 
        CP1500PFCLCD CRCA102-3I1 

Thunderbolt Information: ⓘ
    Apple Inc. thunderbolt_bus

Virtual disks: ⓘ
    Macintosh HD - Data (disk1s1 - APFS) /System/Volumes/Data : 1000.00 GB (219.43 GB free)
        Physical disk: disk0s2 1000.00 GB (219.43 GB free)
    (disk1s2) <not mounted>  [Preboot]: 1000.00 GB
        Physical disk: disk0s2 1000.00 GB 
    (disk1s3) <not mounted>  [Recovery]: 1000.00 GB
        Physical disk: disk0s2 1000.00 GB 
    (disk1s4) /private/var/vm  [VM]: 1000.00 GB
        Physical disk: disk0s2 1000.00 GB 
    Macintosh HD (disk1s5 - APFS) /  [Startup]: 1000.00 GB (219.43 GB free)
        Physical disk: disk0s2 1000.00 GB (219.43 GB free)

System Software: ⓘ
    macOS 10.15.7 (19H1030) - Time since boot: about 3 days 

Gatekeeper: ⓘ
    Mac App Store and identified developers

Possible adware: ⓘ
    Unknown file: /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.SafariBookmarksSyncAgent.plist
        /Library/Apple/System/Library/CoreServices/SafariSupport.bundle/Contents/MacOS/SafariBookmarksSyncAgent
    One possible adware file found. [Remove/Report]

Kernel Extensions: ⓘ
        /Library/Application Support/Logitech.localized/Logitech Options.localized
    [loaded]    com.logitech.manager.kernel.driver (8.20.1 - SDK 10.14) [Lookup]

        /Library/Extensions
    [not loaded]    com.LaCie.ScsiType00 (1.2.13 - SDK 10.5) [Lookup]
    [loaded]    com.sophos.kext.oas (10.0.2 - SDK 10.15) [Lookup]
    [loaded]    com.sophos.kext.sfm (10.0.2 - SDK 10.15) [Lookup]
    [loaded]    com.sophos.nke.swi (10.0.2 - SDK 10.15) [Lookup]

System Launch Agents: ⓘ
    [running]    com.apple.SafariBookmarksSyncAgent.plist (? 49b12d92 f6820329 - installed 2021-04-23)
    [not loaded]    10 Apple tasks
    [loaded]    169 Apple tasks
    [running]    131 Apple tasks

System Launch Daemons: ⓘ
    [failed]    com.apple.metrickitd.plist (Apple, Inc. - installed 2020-09-21)
    [not loaded]    34 Apple tasks
    [loaded]    169 Apple tasks
    [running]    130 Apple tasks

Launch Agents: ⓘ
    [running]    com.bjango.istatmenus.agent.plist (Bjango Pty Ltd - installed 2021-05-01) [Lookup]
    [running]    com.bjango.istatmenus.status.plist (Bjango Pty Ltd - installed 2021-05-01) [Lookup]
    [running]    com.logitech.manager.daemon.plist (Logitech Inc. - installed 2021-04-01) [Lookup]
    [loaded]    com.microsoft.OneDriveStandaloneUpdater.plist (Microsoft Corporation - installed 2021-03-06) [Lookup]
    [not loaded]    com.microsoft.update.agent.plist (Microsoft Corporation - installed 2021-03-18) [Lookup]
    [running]    com.sophos.agent.plist (Sophos - installed 2021-03-19) [Lookup]
    [running]    com.sophos.home.ui.plist (Sophos - installed 2021-03-19) [Lookup]

Launch Daemons: ⓘ
    [loaded]    com.apple.installer.osmessagetracing.plist (? dbb717cc 0 - installed 2019-10-28)
    [running]    com.bjango.istatmenus.daemon.plist (Bjango Pty Ltd - installed 2021-05-01) [Lookup]
    [running]    com.bjango.istatmenus.fans.plist (Bjango Pty Ltd - installed 2021-05-01) [Lookup]
    [loaded]    com.bjango.istatmenus.installerhelper.plist (Bjango Pty Ltd - installed 2021-05-01) [Lookup]
    [running]    com.microsoft.OneDriveStandaloneUpdaterDaemon.plist (Microsoft Corporation - installed 2021-03-06) [Lookup]
    [loaded]    com.microsoft.OneDriveUpdaterDaemon.plist (Microsoft Corporation - installed 2021-03-06) [Lookup]
    [loaded]    com.microsoft.autoupdate.helper.plist (Microsoft Corporation - installed 2021-03-18) [Lookup]
    [loaded]    com.microsoft.office.licensingV2.helper.plist (Microsoft Corporation - installed 2020-10-12) [Lookup]
    [running]    com.sophos.common.servicemanager.plist (Sophos - installed 2021-03-19) [Lookup]
    [running]    com.sophos.sophoscbr.plist (Sophos - installed 2021-03-19) [Lookup]

Internet Plug-ins: ⓘ
    AdobePDFViewerNPAPI: 11.0.12 (installed 2015-07-14) [Lookup]
    nplastpass: 4.1.2 (installed 2017-03-11) [Lookup]
    AdobePDFViewer: 11.0.12 (installed 2015-07-14) [Lookup]

3rd Party Preference Panes: ⓘ
    None

Time Machine: ⓘ
    Time Machine not configured!

Top Processes by CPU: ⓘ
         7%     WindowServer
         6%     SophosScanDLegacy
         4%     kernel_task
         4%     Transmission
         2%     deleted

Top Processes by Memory: ⓘ
    191 MB      SophosScanDLegacy
    132 MB      WindowServer
    128 MB      Finder
    124 MB      MTLCompilerService
    107 MB      kernel_task

Top Processes by Network Use: ⓘ
    Input       Output      Process name
    2.66 GB     23 MB       Transmission
    1 MB        2 MB        SophosMcsAgentD
    1 MB        971 KB      mDNSResponder
    191 KB      92 KB       (Microsoft Outloo)
    128 KB      81 KB       netbiosd

Top Processes by Energy Use: ⓘ
     18.14  WindowServer
      6.52  syspolicyd
      6.46  ReportCrash
      4.36  Transmission

Virtual Memory Information: ⓘ
    10.31 GB    Available RAM
    15 MB       Free RAM
    5.69 GB     Used RAM
    10.30 GB    Cached files
    131 MB      Swap Used

Software installs (last 30 days): ⓘ
    VOX: 3.4 (installed 2021-04-03)
    Enpass: 6.6.1 (installed 2021-04-03)
    AdGuard for Safari: 1.9.13 (installed 2021-04-13)
    Zoom: 5.6.3.706 (installed 2021-04-21)
    The Unarchiver: 4.3.0 (installed 2021-04-24)
    The Unarchiver: 4.3.1 (installed 2021-04-26)
    The Unarchiver: 4.3.3 (installed 2021-04-30)

    Install information may not be complete.

Diagnostics Events (last 3 days for minor events): ⓘ
    2021-05-01 12:20:32    SophosServiceManager.app Crash [Open]
    2021-04-30 16:51:52    Microsoft Outlook.app Hang [Open]
    2021-04-29 10:43:18    Finder.app High CPU use [Open] [Details]
    2021-04-29 09:44:36    signpost_reporter High CPU use [Open] [Details]
    2021-04-28 18:44:59    Firefox.app Hang [Open]
    2021-04-28 13:54:43    Kernel Panic [Open] [Details]
        3rd Party Kernel Extensions: None
    2021-04-28 13:51:33    Last shutdown cause: -62 - System unresponsive
```

**Automatically generated report sent to Apple:**

```
panic(cpu 2 caller 0xffffff7f828faaae): watchdog timeout: no checkins from watchdogd in 305 seconds (703 totalcheckins since monitoring last enabled), shutdown in progress
Backtrace (CPU 2), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff81defabc40 : 0xffffff8001d1763d 
0xffffff81defabc90 : 0xffffff8001e51b25 
0xffffff81defabcd0 : 0xffffff8001e436ae 
0xffffff81defabd20 : 0xffffff8001cbda40 
0xffffff81defabd40 : 0xffffff8001d16d07 
0xffffff81defabe40 : 0xffffff8001d170f7 
0xffffff81defabe90 : 0xffffff80024be898 
0xffffff81defabf00 : 0xffffff7f828faaae 
0xffffff81defabf10 : 0xffffff7f828fa486 
0xffffff81defabf50 : 0xffffff7f8294ed9c 
0xffffff81defabfa0 : 0xffffff8001cbd13e 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.driver.watchdog(1.0)[6C98691D-0510-3A98-9B62-C8FF0B9E3C99]@0xffffff7f828f9000->0xffffff7f82901fff
         com.apple.driver.AppleSMC(3.1.9)[73E3419A-8963-3BB8-8538-1FFDEE1F8583]@0xffffff7f82941000->0xffffff7f8295ffff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily(1.4)[0BC116A3-534A-3990-99CB-09DB34A5EFAA]@0xffffff7f828f0000
            dependency: com.apple.driver.watchdog(1)[6C98691D-0510-3A98-9B62-C8FF0B9E3C99]@0xffffff7f828f9000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[B4389948-0918-363E-8E70-0FBC89B384CA]@0xffffff7f82902000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

Mac OS version:
19H1030

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 19.6.0: Mon Apr 12 20:57:45 PDT 2021; root:xnu-6153.141.28.1~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: BB1171FD-A9E3-3D24-92F7-F4DD45974EFD
Kernel slide:     0x0000000001a00000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8001c00000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8001b00000
System model name: Macmini6,2 (Mac-F65AE981FFA204ED)
System shutdown begun: YES
Panic diags file available: YES (0x0)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 53866778455181
last loaded kext at 369402682856: com.sophos.kext.oas   10.0.2 (addr 0xffffff7f8524b000, size 49152)
last unloaded kext at 418213039604: >!AThunderboltDPOutAdapter  6.2.6 (addr 0xffffff7f842d4000, size 49152)
loaded kexts:
com.sophos.kext.oas 10.0.2
com.sophos.nke.swi  10.0.2
com.sophos.kext.sfm 10.0.2
com.logitech.manager.kernel.driver  8.20.1
@fileutil   20.036.15
>AudioAUUC  1.70
>!AGraphicsDevicePolicy 5.2.7
@AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics   5.2.7
>!AHV   1
|IOUserEthernet 1.0.1
>!AUpstreamUserClient   3.6.8
|IO!BSerialManager  7.0.6f8
>!APlatformEnabler  2.7.0d0
>AGPM   111.4.4
>X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
>!AMikeyHIDDriver   131
>!AMCCSControl  1.14
>pmtelemetry    1
>!AMikeyDriver  283.15
>!A!IHD4000Graphics 14.0.7
@Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X    7.0.0
>!AHDA  283.15
>eficheck   1
>!AThunderboltIP    3.1.4
>!ASMCPDRC  1.0.0
|!ABCM5701Ethernet  10.3.5
>!ALPC  3.1
>AirPort.Brcm4360   1400.1.1
>!AFWOHCI   5.6.2
>!A!IFramebufferCapri   14.0.7
>!A!ISlowAdaptiveClocking   4.0.0
@filesystems.autofs 3.0
>!AIR!C 360
>!AVirtIO   1.0
@filesystems.hfs.kext   522.100.5
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeDataless    1.0.0d1
@BootCache  40
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeZlib    1.0.0
@filesystems.apfs   1412.141.2
@private.KextAudit  1.0
>!ASDXC 1.7.7
>!AAHCIPort 341.140.1
>!AACPIButtons  6.1
>!ARTC  2.0
>!AHPET 1.8
>!ASMBIOS   2.1
>!AACPIEC   6.1
>!AAPIC 1.7
>!A!ICPUPowerManagementClient   222.0.0
$!AImage4   1
@nke.applicationfirewall    303
$TMSafetyNet    8
@!ASystemPolicy 2.0.0
>!A!ICPUPowerManagement 222.0.0
|EndpointSecurity   1
|IOAVB!F    850.1
@plugin.IOgPTPPlugin    840.3
>DspFuncLib 283.15
@kext.OSvKernDSPLib 529
>!ASMBus!C  1.0.18d1
|IOFireWireIP   2.3.0
|IONDRVSupport  576.1
@!AGPUWrangler  5.2.7
>X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
>!AHDA!C    283.15
|IOHDA!F    283.15
|IOEthernetAVB!C    1.1.0
>IOPlatformPlugin!F 6.0.0d8
>!ASMBusPCI 1.0.14d1
|IO80211!F  1200.12.2b1
|IOSkywalk!F    1
>mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
>corecapture    1.0.4
|IOFireWire!F   4.7.5
|IOAccelerator!F2   438.7.4
@!AGraphicsDeviceControl    5.2.7
|IOGraphics!F   576.1
>!AGraphicsControl  5.2.7
|IOSlowAdaptiveClocking!F   1.0.0
@kext.triggers  1.0
|Broadcom!BHost!CUSBTransport   7.0.6f8
|IO!BHost!CUSBTransport 7.0.6f8
|IO!BHost!CTransport    7.0.6f8
>usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.2
>usb.networking 5.0.0
>usb.!UHostCompositeDevice  1.2
>usb.!UHub  1.2
|IOAudio!F  300.2
@vecLib.kext    1.2.0
|IOSerial!F 11
|IOSurface  269.11
@filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext 1
>!AThunderboltDPInAdapter   6.2.6
>!AThunderboltDPAdapter!F   6.2.6
>!AThunderboltPCIDownAdapter    2.5.4
|IOAHCIBlock!S  316.100.5
>!AThunderboltNHI   5.8.6
|IOThunderbolt!F    7.6.1
|IOAHCI!F   290.0.1
>usb.!UEHCIPCI  1.2
>usb.!UEHCI 1.2
>usb.!UXHCIPCI  1.2
>usb.!UXHCI 1.2
>!AEFINVRAM 2.1
>!AEFIRuntime   2.1
|IOSMBus!F  1.1
$quarantine 4
$sandbox    300.0
@kext.!AMatch   1.0.0d1
>DiskImages 493.0.0
>!AFDEKeyStore  28.30
>!AEffaceable!S 1.0
>!ASSE  1.0
>!AKeyStore 2
>!UTDM  489.120.1
|IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice  422.120.3
>!ACredentialManager    1.0
>KernelRelayHost    1
>!ASEPManager   1.0.1
>IOSlaveProcessor   1
|IOTimeSync!F   840.3
|IONetworking!F 3.4
|IOUSBMass!SDriver  157.140.1
|IOSCSIArchitectureModel!F  422.120.3
|IO!S!F 2.1
|CoreAnalytics!F    1
>!AMobileFileIntegrity  1.0.5
@kext.CoreTrust 1
>IO!BHIDDriver  7.0.6f8
|IO!B!F 7.0.6f8
|IO!BPacketLogger   7.0.6f8
|IOUSBHIDDriver 900.4.2
|IOHID!F    2.0.0
|IOReport!F 47
|IOUSB!F    900.4.2
|IOUSBHost!F    1.2
>!UHostMergeProperties  1.2
>usb.!UCommon   1.0
>!ABusPower!C   1.0
>!AACPIPlatform 6.1
>!ASMC  3.1.9
>watchdog   1
|IOPCI!F    2.9
|IOACPI!F   1.4
@kec.pthread    1
@kec.Libm   1
@kec.corecrypto 1.0
```

**After the system restart:**

```
EtreCheck version: 3.4.6 (460)
Report generated 2021-05-02 17:09:44
Download EtreCheck from https://etrecheck.com
Runtime: 7:19
Performance: Below Average

Click the [Lookup] links for more information from Apple Support Communities.
Click the [Details] links for more information about that line.
Click the [Remove/Report] links to remove adware or update the whitelist of legitimate software.

Hardware Information: ⓘ
    Mac mini (Late 2012) 
    [Technical Specifications] - [User Guide] - [Warranty & Service]
    Mac mini - model: Macmini6,2
    1 2.6 GHz Quad-Core Intel Core i7 (i7-3720QM) CPU: 4-core
    16 GB RAM Upgradeable - [Instructions]
        BANK 0/DIMM0
            8 GB DDR3 1600 MHz ok
        BANK 1/DIMM0
            8 GB DDR3 1600 MHz ok
    Handoff/Airdrop2: supported
    Wireless:  en1: Unknown
    iCloud Quota: 4.97 GB available

Video Information: ⓘ
    Intel HD Graphics 4000 - VRAM: 1536 MB
        HP ZR30w 2560 x 1600

Disk Information: ⓘ
    APPLE HDD HTS541010A9E662 disk0: (1 TB) (Rotational)
    [Show SMART report]
        EFI (disk0s1 - MS-DOS FAT32) <not mounted>  [EFI]: 210 MB 
        (disk0s2) <not mounted>  [APFS Container]: 1000.00 GB

USB Information: ⓘ
     USB20Bus 
         hub_device 
             hub_device 
                Apple, Inc. IR Receiver 
                Apple Inc. BRCM20702 Hub 
                    Apple Inc. Bluetooth USB Host Controller 
     USB20Bus 
         hub_device 
             hub_device 
     USB30Bus 
        CP1500PFCLCD CRCA102-3I1 

Thunderbolt Information: ⓘ
    Apple Inc. thunderbolt_bus

Virtual disks: ⓘ
    Macintosh HD - Data (disk1s1 - APFS) /System/Volumes/Data : 1000.00 GB (387.17 GB free)
        Physical disk: disk0s2 1000.00 GB (387.17 GB free)
    (disk1s2) <not mounted>  [Preboot]: 1000.00 GB
        Physical disk: disk0s2 1000.00 GB 
    (disk1s3) <not mounted>  [Recovery]: 1000.00 GB
        Physical disk: disk0s2 1000.00 GB 
    (disk1s4) /private/var/vm  [VM]: 1000.00 GB
        Physical disk: disk0s2 1000.00 GB 
    Macintosh HD (disk1s5 - APFS) /  [Startup]: 1000.00 GB (387.17 GB free)
        Physical disk: disk0s2 1000.00 GB (387.17 GB free)

System Software: ⓘ
    macOS 10.15.7 (19H1030) - Time since boot: about 2 hours

Gatekeeper: ⓘ
    Mac App Store and identified developers

Possible adware: ⓘ
    Unknown file: /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.SafariBookmarksSyncAgent.plist
        /Library/Apple/System/Library/CoreServices/SafariSupport.bundle/Contents/MacOS/SafariBookmarksSyncAgent
    One possible adware file found. [Remove/Report]

Kernel Extensions: ⓘ
        /Library/Application Support/Logitech.localized/Logitech Options.localized
    [loaded]    com.logitech.manager.kernel.driver (8.20.1 - SDK 10.14) [Lookup]

        /Library/Extensions
    [not loaded]    com.LaCie.ScsiType00 (1.2.13 - SDK 10.5) [Lookup]
    [loaded]    com.sophos.kext.oas (10.0.2 - SDK 10.15) [Lookup]
    [loaded]    com.sophos.kext.sfm (10.0.2 - SDK 10.15) [Lookup]
    [loaded]    com.sophos.nke.swi (10.0.2 - SDK 10.15) [Lookup]

System Launch Agents: ⓘ
    [running]    com.apple.SafariBookmarksSyncAgent.plist (? 49b12d92 f6820329 - installed 2021-04-23)
    [not loaded]    10 Apple tasks
    [loaded]    185 Apple tasks
    [running]    115 Apple tasks

System Launch Daemons: ⓘ
    [not loaded]    34 Apple tasks
    [loaded]    183 Apple tasks
    [running]    117 Apple tasks

Launch Agents: ⓘ
    [running]    com.logitech.manager.daemon.plist (Logitech Inc. - installed 2021-04-01) [Lookup]
    [loaded]    com.microsoft.OneDriveStandaloneUpdater.plist (Microsoft Corporation - installed 2021-03-06) [Lookup]
    [not loaded]    com.microsoft.update.agent.plist (Microsoft Corporation - installed 2021-05-02) [Lookup]
    [running]    com.sophos.agent.plist (Sophos - installed 2021-03-19) [Lookup]
    [running]    com.sophos.home.ui.plist (Sophos - installed 2021-03-19) [Lookup]

Launch Daemons: ⓘ
    [loaded]    com.apple.installer.osmessagetracing.plist (? dbb717cc 0 - installed 2019-10-28)
    [running]    com.microsoft.OneDriveStandaloneUpdaterDaemon.plist (Microsoft Corporation - installed 2021-03-06) [Lookup]
    [loaded]    com.microsoft.OneDriveUpdaterDaemon.plist (Microsoft Corporation - installed 2021-03-06) [Lookup]
    [loaded]    com.microsoft.autoupdate.helper.plist (Microsoft Corporation - installed 2021-05-02) [Lookup]
    [loaded]    com.microsoft.office.licensingV2.helper.plist (Microsoft Corporation - installed 2020-10-12) [Lookup]
    [running]    com.sophos.common.servicemanager.plist (Sophos - installed 2021-03-19) [Lookup]
    [running]    com.sophos.sophoscbr.plist (Sophos - installed 2021-03-19) [Lookup]

Internet Plug-ins: ⓘ
    AdobePDFViewerNPAPI: 11.0.12 (installed 2015-07-14) [Lookup]
    nplastpass: 4.1.2 (installed 2017-03-11) [Lookup]
    AdobePDFViewer: 11.0.12 (installed 2015-07-14) [Lookup]

3rd Party Preference Panes: ⓘ
    None

Time Machine: ⓘ
    Time Machine not configured!

Top Processes by CPU: ⓘ
        18%     WindowServer
        13%     TextEdit
         6%     kernel_task
         4%     mdsync
         2%     LogiMgrDaemon

Top Processes by Memory: ⓘ
    395 MB      firefox
    309 MB      SophosScanDLegacy
    245 MB      plugin-container
    190 MB      plugin-container
    174 MB      MTLCompilerService

Top Processes by Network Use: ⓘ
    Input       Output      Process name
    8 MB        2 MB        tor.real
    159 KB      312 KB      SophosMcsAgentD
    122 KB      51 KB       (Microsoft Outloo)
    34 KB       29 KB       mDNSResponder
    5 KB        38 KB       apsd

Top Processes by Energy Use: ⓘ
      4.88  WindowServer
      3.86  mdsync
      2.56  firefox
      0.98  LogiMgrDaemon

Virtual Memory Information: ⓘ
    10.08 GB    Available RAM
    2.86 GB     Free RAM
    5.92 GB     Used RAM
    7.22 GB     Cached files
    0 B         Swap Used

Software installs (last 30 days): ⓘ
    VOX: 3.4 (installed 2021-04-03)
    Enpass: 6.6.1 (installed 2021-04-03)
    AdGuard for Safari: 1.9.13 (installed 2021-04-13)
    Zoom: 5.6.3.706 (installed 2021-04-21)
    The Unarchiver: 4.3.0 (installed 2021-04-24)
    The Unarchiver: 4.3.1 (installed 2021-04-26)
    The Unarchiver: 4.3.3 (installed 2021-04-30)
    Microsoft AutoUpdate: (null) (installed 2021-05-02)
    Microsoft Excel: (null) (installed 2021-05-02)
    Microsoft OneNote: (null) (installed 2021-05-02)
    Microsoft PowerPoint: (null) (installed 2021-05-02)
    Microsoft Word: (null) (installed 2021-05-02)
    Microsoft Outlook: (null) (installed 2021-05-02)

    Install information may not be complete.

Diagnostics Events (last 3 days for minor events): ⓘ
    2021-05-02 14:32:55    Kernel Panic [Open] [Details]
        3rd Party Kernel Extensions: None
    2021-05-02 14:30:13    Last shutdown cause: -62 - System unresponsive
    2021-05-02 14:06:46    Keynote.app Hang [Open]
    2021-05-02 13:40:29    Microsoft Word.app Hang [Open]
    2021-05-01 23:37:37    logd Crash [Open]
        Cause:        dyld3 mode
        BUG IN LIBTRACE: Bad timesync db entry, file rotated
    2021-05-01 21:39:44    Sophos Scan.app High CPU use [Open] [Details]
    2021-05-01 12:20:32    SophosServiceManager.app Crash [Open]
    2021-04-30 16:51:52    Microsoft Outlook.app Hang [Open]
```

Comment: I’ve reformatted your post to use code formatting for the log output. Please look at the presentation of your post in the preview and format appropriately so it can be understood and [edit] further if appropriate.

Comment: Your log indicates a watchdog timeout, please try the solutions from the linked question and [edit] with the results if they did not solve the issue.

Comment: Thank you very kindly for your most appreciated help, @grg! Could you please help me understand what the reason for this "watchdog timeout" problem was? Was it something I did wrong? Apps I am using? Outdated hardware? I am not a Guru, and do need your help badly... I sent many reports to Apple, but so far they did not solve the problem, unfortunately enough.